# global stylesheet loading takes extremely long

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I load a global stylesheet with

```
QFile File(":/styleDark.qss");
File.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QString StyleSheet = QLatin1String(File.readAll());
File.close();

qApp->setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
```

Everything works fine but it takes **between 3 and 4 seconds** to load the stylesheet. It does not matter if the stylesheet contains only 1 line or 500 lines.
Is there a way to speed up this time?

Qt5 on Windows 10

Comment: Step 1) do an optimized release build rather than an unoptimized debug build when doing performance measurements.

Comment: What line does take 3 seconds? How did you measure it?

Comment: I used a QElapsedTimer to meassure the time.

Just qApp->setStyleSheet(StyleSheet) take over 3 seconds.

Take the same time in release build.

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide a [mcve]?  I'd imagine the time taken to apply a stylesheet depends not only on the size of the stylesheet itself but also on the number of elements to which it must be applied.  i.e. lots of QWidgets ==> lots of time.